# "Using" directive fails within template

Tags: c++, templates, using

I understand that the member names of a base-class template are hidden within the scope of a derived class, and therefore must be accessed using `this->foo` or `Base<T>::foo`.  However, I recall that C++ also allows you to use the `using` keyword, which can come in handy in a derived-class function which frequently accesses a base-class variable.  So, in order to avoid cluttering up the function with `this->` everywhere, I'd like to use the `using` keyword.

I know I've done this before, but for whatever reason I can't get it to work now.  I'm probably just doing something stupid, but the following code won't compile:

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
   int x;
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
   void dosomething()
   {
     using Base<T>::x; // gives compiler error
     x = 0;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derived<int> d;
}
```

The error, (with GCC 4.3) is: `error: ‘Base<T>’ is not a namespace`

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because C++ language has no such feature and never had. A using-declaration for a class member must be a *member declaration*. This means that you can only use in class scope, but never in local scope. This all has absolutely nothing to do with templates.

In other words, you can place your using-declaration into class scope

```
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
  ...
  using Base<T>::x;
  ...
};
```

but you can't have it inside a function.

Using-declarations for namespace members can be placed in local scope, but using-declarations for class members cannot be. This is why the error message complains about `Base<T>` not being a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
   int x;
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
   using Base<T>::x;
   void dosomething()
   {
     x = 0;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derived<int> d;
}
```

As others said, it is working only class scope.

Answer (score 3):

Outside class scope (if you are in a block etc), you can only name namespace members in a using declaration.

If you don't want to place that using declaration into the scope of `Derived` (which IMO is the favorable solution), your other option is to use a reference

```
int &x = this->x;
x = 0;
```

It should be noted that this is semantically different, because it

- Forces a definition to exist for `Base<T>::x`, which might not be the case for static const data members
- Forces `Base<T>::x` to be of type `int&` or be convertible to type `int&`.

Otherwise, if you want to avoid using `this->` all again, I don't see other options.